# How to zsh pipe to grep to match remote branches beginning with 'orgin/'

Tags: bash, git, grep, zsh

I tried this:

```
git branch -r --merged | grep '^origin/'
```

But I get nothing...

When I remove the caret:

```
  ✗ git branch -r --merged | grep 'origin/'
    origin/HEAD -> origin/master
    origin/master
```

I would like to make the regexp only match origin if the string begins with origin.

Answer (score 2):

The output does not begin with `origin`, it begins with whitespace, so you need:

```
git branch -r --merged | grep -E '^[ ]+origin/'
```

(Although, of course, in your second example, all lines would match.)